# Use non-ascii characters in an app engine application

Tags: python, google-app-engine

How can I handle a non-ascii url in App Engine? For example http://example.org/Ñöñ-ÅŞÇİİ.

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication([("/Ñöñ-ÅŞÇİİ", MainPage)], debug=True)
```

I have tried putting # -- coding: utf-8 -- but it didn't work.

Edit:
I get HTTP 404 Not Found.

Comment: "It didn't work" how? What error did you get? What went wrong? We're not going to be very helpful if you make us guess.

Comment: I get HTTP 404 Not Found. Whether I use  # -- coding: utf-8 --  or u"/Ñöñ-ÅŞÇİİ". Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules are matched against the URLEncoded form of the string, so you need to use that instead. You can see this by looking at the logs for the dev_appserver, where you should see something like this:

```
INFO     2011-03-25 00:59:56,577 dev_appserver.py:3317] "GET /%C3%91%C3%B6%C3%B1-%C3%85%C5%9E%C3%87%C4%B0%C4%B0 HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

An easy way to define your rules would be like so:

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication([(urllib.quote("/Ñöñ-ÅŞÇİİ"), MainPage)], debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your browser will be URL-encoding any characters that dont fit [RFC1738](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt)

So your route will probably have to be something like:

```
/%C3%91%C3%B6%C3%B1-%C3%85%C5%9E%C3%87%C4%B0%C4%B0
```

to match

```
/Ñöñ-ÅŞÇİİ
```